# Logistic Regression: Are thresholds and non-negative constraints equivalent?

Tags: convex-optimization, regression

For interpretability, I want to restrict the weights $\beta_i$ in a logisitic regression

$$p(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{- \beta^Tx}} $$

to be non-negative, i.e. $\beta_i \geq 0$.

Since the negative maximum likelihood of the model is known to be convex, the problem can be solved using convex optimisation.

At first sight, this constrained optimisation should be different from fitting a standard logistic regression and then setting all the negative weights to 0.
At least my implementation in Python yields different results.

But since the function I want to minimise is convex, shouldn't be the optimal solution of the constrained problem be the point where all weights that are normally negative are now just set to 0?
Because this is the closest one gets to the unique minimum in non-constrained space, assuming it exists.

Where am I going wrong? Are the two approaches equivalent or not?

Comment: No they are not equivalent. Your intuition about being the closest one to the unique minimum for the unconstrained problem is not correct. There might not even be a unique minimum given only convexity.

Comment: The two approaches are definitely not equivalent. "shouldn't the optimal solution of the constrained problem be the point..." No, that does not follow.

Comment: By the way, why does having nonnegative weights improve interpretability?

Comment: @littleO Now that you mention it I don't really know why they care so much but a lot of people, for instance especially those studying nonnegative matrix factorization, always mention that nonnegativity is important for interpretability.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! If I understand you correctly, where I got wrong was to assume that the closest point in euclidean space is also the one that minimises the objective function given the constraints. In hindsight that seems obviously not true.

Comment: @backboltz37 indeed, this is the error. Changing the negative weights to 0 is definitely the projection of the weight vector onto the nonnegative orthant but this projection might not be meaningful relative to the problem you are studying.